# Change the Table's Alias name runtime in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a application contains IdentityDbContext and I want to select data using ServiceStack.OrmLite and I want to know how can I change the alias name

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRole");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogin");
    }
}
```

I tried the code at below but it's not working:

```
ModelDefinition<User>.Definition.Alias = "Users";
ModelDefinition<IdentityRole>.Definition.Alias = "Roles";
ModelDefinition<IdentityUserRole<string>>.Definition.Alias = "UserRoles";
ModelDefinition<IdentityUserClaim<string>>.Definition.Alias = "UserClaims";
ModelDefinition<IdentityUserLogin<string>>.Definition.Alias = "UserLogins";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the table metadata that OrmLite use for each Type using the `GetModelMetadata()` extension method, e.g:

```
var tableMeta = type.GetModelMetadata();
tableMeta.Alias = "NewTableName";
```

Comment: Hello @mythz . Here i have a problem when i try to read same model we have from EntityFramework IdentityUser we will see a error like this: `PostgresException: 42703: column "Roles" does not exist` because the type of the `Roles` property is `ICollection<TUserRole>` . Do you have any solution for that?